# A group presentation for $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation

I know that the only groups of order 4 are $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ up to isomorphisms.
And I also know that the group presentation of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is $\left ( a:a^4=1 \right )$.

Naturally, I thought the group presentation of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is $\left ( a,b:a^2=1,b^2=1 \right )$.
But I'm not sure this presentation really indicates  $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

For example, if $A=\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} &1 \\ 
-1 &-\sqrt{2} 
\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{3} &1 \\
-2 &-\sqrt{3}
\end{pmatrix}\in \left ( M(2, \mathbb{R}), \cdot  \right )$, then a group $\left ( A,B \right )$ has a presentation $\left ( A,B:A^2=E,B^2=E \right )$ but $AB\neq BA$ and thus this group is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Where did I misunderstand?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The relations $a^2=1$ and $b^2=1$ are not enough to specify $C_2\times C_2$ (they actually specify the free product $C_2*C_2$); one needs the additional relation $ab=ba$.

Comment: Alternatively, the presentation $(a,b:g^2=1\,\,\forall g)$ works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that $\langle a, b | a^2 = b^2 = 1\rangle$ is not enough to specify the given group: In fact, this is the large non-abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\ast$ is the free product. Its elements can be thought of as sequences of various forms: $$abab\dots abab, baba\dots baba, abab\dots aba, baba\dots bab$$ So it's necessary to add a bit more; the easiest way would be to modify the definition to add a commutativity relation:

$$\langle a, b | a^2 = b^2 = 1, ab = ba\rangle$$

Then one can rearrange the given sequences, finding that all elements are of the form $a^k b^j$; then there are exactly four group elements, corresponding to the possible parities of $k$ and $j$.

There are, of course, other ways to represent this group.

Answer (score 2):

Using your original presentation, imagine writing words: they're all of the form $\ldots abab\ldots$. If you add the commutation relation $ab = ba$ to the presentation, these words collapse to be of the form $a^k b^j$ for $k, j = 0$ or $1$. In particular, there are at most 4 elements to any group that satisfies the presentation $(a, b : a^2 = b^2 = 1, ab = ba)$, and since $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ satisfies it, you've found its presentation.

Answer (score 1):

This post can be a complement of @T bonger's post. We know that every finite group has a finite presentation and you know that. But having a finite presentation *doesn't* give us that the group itself is of *finite* order necessarily ( See Boger's free product of two cyclic groups). So for not to face these cases, we use an idea called [The deficiency of group presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group#Deficiency). In your group, as it is in line $3$, the deficiency is zero so according to  [Mcdonald's theorem](http://www-circa.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~colinc/TGps/hout1.pdf), it is **infinite** and this is not what you wanted so we should make it finite, so we need additional relation to be added to other relations inside the presentation (Line $3$). What would this new presentation be? As you are working on an abelian group Klein $4$- group so the trivial relation is $ab=ba$.